# Sending post request and getting error "undefined is not a function"

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http-post

I created an AngularJs app.

I have a controller and when i click on a specific button i need to send information to server.
The controller has a function called "button_clicked"

```
$scope.button_clicked = function () {

    1     var currentObject = $scope.getCurrentObject;

    2    $http.post(ENV.server_prefix + 'object/addObject/', currentObject)
    3        .then(function (data, status) {
    4          //Doing something!!
    5       }).error(function (data, status, params) {
    6           alert(data);
    7       });
    };
```

When i am running the code, the callback is executed. However in console in get an error:
"undefined is not a function" and it points to line 5

Why this error and how to handle it?

Answer (score 3):

Try using `success`:

```
$scope.button_clicked = function () {

     var currentObject = $scope.getCurrentObject;

    $http.post(ENV.server_prefix + 'object/addObject/', currentObject)
        .success(function (data, status) {
          //Doing something!!
       }).error(function (data, status, params) {
           alert(data);
       });
};
```

When you use `then`, the error handler should be passed as a second argument:

```
$http.post(ENV.server_prefix + 'object/addObject/', currentObject)
    .then(function (data, status) {
      //Doing something!!
   }, function (data, status, params) {
       alert(data);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You're mixing up the syntax for `then` here. If you use `then` it expects two arguments, the first being a success-handler and the second being an error-handler.

```
$scope.button_clicked = function () {

    var currentObject = $scope.getCurrentObject;

    $http.post(ENV.server_prefix + 'object/addObject/', currentObject)
        .then(function (data, status) {
                //Doing something!!
            }, function(data, status, params) {
                alert(data);
            });
    });
};
```